# Resizing,moving and scaling image and text divs wiith browser resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I thought this would be a pretty common question to look for in Google but I can't seem to find an answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a web page with full size re-sizable background image. Something like this:

```
html
{
    background-size:contain;
    background: black url(../images/myimage.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center; 
}
```

On the image I have a section dedicated to a z-layer DIV that contains an image and another z-layer DIV that contains some text.

When I start re-sizing the browser window my page DIVs go crazy. They actually stay static to where they are while the page and its background image is getting smaller.

How can I make sure that my DIVs that contain images, links and text are always at the correct location no matter what user's screen resolution is or no matter how do they re-size the browser. CSS? Javascript ? JQuery ? What's the best way to do it ?

Thank you in advance !!!

p.s. Please let me know if something isn't clear and a sample is needed.

Comment: can you push your code for better understanding

Comment: There is no good example yet unfortunately. I'm just trying to figuire out a way to do this but here it is so you have an idea:
http://livestutterfree.com/page/

Depending on what your screen resolution is or how you resize the browser - see how the text layer get all dislocated on the page ?

Comment: In this example, the movement is because there is no horizontal location assigned to the #content1 div, it moves when the page is resized because it is not assigned a left.  The #element1 div stays in the same location relative to the left side of the screen because it has a left value.

Comment: ok, so lets's say if left:20px; and top:20px (for example ) is assigned you're saying it will always stick to the borders and re-scale ? I'll give it a try.
How about resizing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css is your best bet.  You'll want to set the div's position to either `fixed`, `absolute`, or `relative`, depending on the case. `fixed` will cause the item to maintain it's location when the user scrolls, while `absolute` will cause the item to scroll with the rest of the page, and will go wherever you tell it regardless of if it's inside something else. `relative` gets it's positioning relative to any parent container elements it's inside of, or the window itself if it's not inside another container element.

If it's `fixed` or `absolute`, assigning a `right` will maintain it's position aligned to the right of the screen if the user re sizes the window or depending on resolution, and `left`, `top`, and `bottom` will all act accordingly as well.  You can assign them a percentage, which will also change accordingly per resolution or resizing. Or you can assign a hard coded value in pixels, centimeters, millimeters, inches, [etc...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  Here's a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mf5ru/) as code example

Comment: Thank you. I'm running into some other unrelated problems but that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion do the following:

- remove the extra white spacing from the background image
- -remove the background image from the body tag and use a main div like  and place all your content inside
  it.
- -remove the div 'element1' and add the background color to 'content1' div itself
- -to handle the positioning of the content based on screen resolutions,  there are 2 approaches:- 1)Use CSS media queries 2)Use relative positioning using css
- -Using Css media queries can become tedious if you are supporting a wide array of resolutions, so instead use css relative positioning.

e.g

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content1">Content</div> 
</div> 

.wrapper{ position:relative; width:100%; overflow:hidden; background:url(yourBgImage.jpg);background-size:100% 100%;}
.content1{position:absolute; top:20%; left:10%;}
```